# stripping files extention but only if it exists

Tags: batch-file

I have a question.

I would like to know how i can strip a files extention from its name but only if it exists to begin with, thus simply stripping the last four characters wont work.

I use batch

this causes my delema:

```
rem SETS THE NAME THE USER WANTS TO SAVE THE FILE AS...
SET /P MY_NAME=   FILE NAME: 

REM SAVES FILE AS INDICATED BY USER...
ECHO %MYTEXT% > "%MY_DIR%\%MY_NAME%.txt"
```

I could leave the extention completely off  (second line of code) But then the user might not add the extention there self.

Comment: Batch exclusive to Windows as far as I was lead to belive. Example of what? all I have masterd is how to strip the last four characters of a sting. now it's not enougth as my program asks the user for a file name they may actually type it with the extention, resulting in a file name such as example.txt.txt or without resulting in example.txt HF

Comment: to check if file exists use `if [not] exist %myfile% (something)`.To get file name without extension use `for /f %%F in (%myfile%) do ( echo %%~nF)`

Comment: how about `SET /P MY_NAME=   FILE NAME (without extension): `?

Answer (score 0):

[Documenting that this question is answered by @npocmaka]

To check if file exists use:

```
if [not] exist %myfile% (something)
```

To get file name without extension use:

```
for /f %%F in (%myfile%) do ( echo %%~nF)
```